# 0 artifacts were found when try to upload to Artifactory from root folder using declarative jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am using this code snippet to upload MSI file to artifactory from root D drive
but for some reason 0 artifacts were found Although the file exist

this is the log:
For pattern: D:/subdir/subdir/examplepipeline/Release/KB*.msi 0 artifacts were found.

```
script { 
             def kbPattern = "D:/subdir/subdir/examplepipeline/Release/KB*.msi"
             def server = Artifactory.server 'artifacrtoyID'
             def uploadSpec = """{
                "files": [
                {
                   "pattern": "${kbPattern}",
                   "target": "someRepo/"
                }]
             }"""

             server.upload(uploadSpec) 
        }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Everything it is sounds fine, look at if the path target is correct!